# Errno 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - How to debug?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine for the first time and I'm sort of confused about this error, I can't understand how to debug this any further.

I created an application under my account, then I'm trying to upload a python file into it via Google App Engine Launcher. But I keeping getting this error.

```
08:39 PM Host: appengine.google.com
08:39 PM Application: gappproxytestapp; version: 1
08:39 PM 
Starting update of app: gappproxytestapp, version: 1
08:39 PM Getting current resource limits.
2012-11-13 20:40:32,505 ERROR appcfg.py:2202 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4322, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4313, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2599, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4048, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3065, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3047, in UpdateVersion
    lambda path: self.opener(os.path.join(basepath, path), 'rb'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2172, in DoUpload
    self.resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 357, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 328, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 389, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    **return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 383, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
2012-11-13 20:40:32 (Process exited with code 1)**

You can close this window now.
```

How do I debug this further? Seems like urllib2 is having problems with HTTPS. But that's strange because I'm not behind any local proxy and I've never had any other HTTPS problems.

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @RTF When I closed the Google App Engine Launcher and started it again, and attempted uploading the app, it worked.

Comment: @gsinha, great -- so please post this as an answer so it can be upvoted and this old Q won't appear as "unanswered" any more!-)

Comment: For anyone else seeing this, as per Justin Beckwith's comment in [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982261/has-the-google-app-engine-launcher-for-mac-osx-been-deprecated#comment65351303_38982261) it is recommended to use the new [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) to deploy via 'gcloud app deploy' instead of the very old App Engine Launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I closed the Google App Engine Launcher and started it again, and attempted uploading the app, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It does not work even I try different different PCs, operating systems, updating the latest SDK, or other solutions. I doubt that it is the problem of the Google App Engine Server side. After waiting for one day, everything is fine. So if you have the same problem, it may be a good choice to **wait for one day**.