# Has the Google App Engine Launcher for MAC OSX been deprecated?

Tags: google-app-engine

Sorry if this is off topic. If it is, please let me know where to post. I don't see a GAE site on SE. I can't update my Google App Engine Launcher. All the new install documentation I have found omits anything about it. I have version 1.9.37.

There is no .dmg file or .app file in the current GAE SDK downloads. I can't find a separate download either. I have not been able to find a statement by Google in any release notes or bug reports, etc. So again the question is:

Has the Google App Engine Launcher for MAC OSX  been deprecated?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a posting on this in the Google forum as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/kwFcjqE3qC4 If anything comes of that I'll post that here. Thanks.

Comment: I would really recommend not using that (we're cleaning up the docs).  Most of our energy here is spent on the [Cloud SDK](http://cloud.google.com/sdk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's helpful!

Comment: I've been using the GAE Launcher for years... and it's silently deprecated... well, I am not surprised.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone looking: you can still [download it here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/download#appengine_sdk) !!

This is a godsend. Honestly dev_appserver.py is easy to work with (just run `dev_appserver.py .` in your app top level directory then browse to localhost:8080)

To deploy it was a mess: you need appcfg.py, which I couldn't find anywhere. I tried to install from the gcloud things but their install script didn't work for me. And then I found the old app. Working great!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped me 

Comment: You saved me.. I forgot the name "Google Appengine Launcher".

Comment: This is great, I liked it too, but the problem is that the old Launcher app is a Python 2 thing, and as of this month, Goog is moving on from Py 2, no more support.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas mentioned in his reply, for a time, there was still the ability to download the App (from an old link) and use it. Starting from November (or December 2020), deploying via the old GAE Launcher is no longer supported because Google has shifted to using `Cloud Build` for deployment and the `appcfg.py update app.yaml` command did not use that.

We have created a replacement for GAE Launcher. You can find it on https://nocommandline.com. Simply put, it is a GUI for GAE and offers same functionality (with some improvements) as the old GAE Launcher

Comment: This is now the best option. The link below no longer works.